# Equating Coefficients - Meaning and Example

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to understand what "Equating the Coefficients " means

I am given the following:

$$ t_1 \left(t_2+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)+\frac{2 t_2}{x}=t_1^2 b_2'+t_1 \left(2 b_2 t_1'+b_1'\right)+b_1 t_1'+b_0'+\frac{d R}{d x}$$

and the author continues...

"Equating coefficients by $t_1$, we get the following system of equations"

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
b_2' & = & 0 \\
2 b_2 t_1'+b_1' & = & t_2+\frac{1}{x+1}\\
b_1 t_1'+b_0'+\frac{d R}{d x} & = & \frac{2 t_2}{x}
   \end{eqnarray}
$$

"From the first equation, we find"

$$b_2=c_2$$

"From the second equation, we find"

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 b_1+2 c_2 t_1 & =\int (t_2+\frac{1}{x+1}) \\
\end{array}$$

I am unclear how they are arriving at this result. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice the expression $t_1 \left(t_2+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$ on the LHS and the expression $t_1 \left(2 b_2 t_1'+b_1'\right)$? Because of their similar form, we can equate those and then you equate the other similar expressions, so you can figure out how to make the LHS = RHS. Can you now figure it out?

Comment: Think at your equality as an equality between polynomials in the indeterminate $t_1$ but with "parametric" coefficients. What does it mean that two polynomials are equal?

Comment: @Moo - Ok so I see that one. But why wouldn't $t_1 \left(t_2+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$ equate with $b_1 t_1$

Comment: I find the existence of the $t_{1}'$ makes all this pretty dodgy; it seems to me to undercut the "$t_1$ is an indeterminate" approach (which I agree is what is usually intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it means equating coefficients of each linearly independent variable from LHS and RHS. So that the identity 0=0 remains true for any value of the variables.

Here the linearly independent variables are $t_1$ and $t_1^2$ .

Comment: Ok - I think I got this. Thanks.